# Oblique collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

A particle moving horizontally collides with a fixed inclined plane at 60° to the horizontal. If it bounces vertically, the coefficient of restitution is ?

[image: this is what I did]

Energy can't be conserved as the collision is not elastic and neither can momentum be conserved as an external force normal is acting on the particle, please tell me what should I do next I am stuck here.

Comment: Consider what is happening in the horizontal direction and what is happening in the vertical direction.

Comment: Can I conserve the momentum along the horizontal

Comment: Sorry, that suggestion wasn't so useful - I didn't read the question carefully.  Thy asking yourself how different is the problem compared to if it were all rotated 60 degrees clockwise so that the surface was horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that the plane can only exert a force on the particle in the direction normal to its surface.  This, and the fact that you know that the final velocity has no horizontal component, tells you what the vertical component of the final velocity must be, from which you can calculate the coefficient of restitution.

Comment: Can you please explain the second point, how can I find the vertical component of the velocity.

Comment: The momentum change due to the collision will be in the direction normal to the face of the incline. That momentum change will have a horizontal component and a vertical component. The horizontal component will cancel the initial velocity, but if you know the horizontal component and the direction, you can find the vertical component.

Answer (score 0):

> neither can momentum be conserved as an external force normal is acting on the particle

The external force acting on the particle is the normal force. But then let's just include this normal force in our system, by expanding our system to include the Wall+Earth. Now you have a system with no external forces interfering.

Earth gains negligibly little speed from this impact. So the before-momentum and the after-moment of Earth are both $0$. And then you can use the momentum conservation law to continue from here.

Comment: Wouldn't mg be an external force acting on the particle

Comment: True, but not if the whole earth is included in the system. But in any case, the weight is acting equally on both so it doesn't make a difference if it was an external force.

Comment: So initial momentum $mv_o$ = $mv_1$ which gives $v_o=v_1$ final momentum,  but this does not give the right answer

Comment: This is the right answer :) Just remember only to take the perpendicular speed $v_x$. Only the perpendicular motion is being influenced by the collision.

Comment: @Gem I now notice that you said this is a non elastic collision. In that case my comments here are not correct, I apologize for that. Why would this be non elastic, though? I don't see that in the problem text.